# How to configure IPV4 address and Subnet Mask

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin iOS we can connect to a Wi-Fi network using SSID and password as below

```
var config = new NEHotspotConfiguration(SSID, Password, false) { 
JoinOnce = false };

var configManager = new NEHotspotConfigurationManager();

await configManager.ApplyConfigurationAsync(config);
```

provided HotSpotConfiguration is added in the app entitlement.

My question is

1. Is it possible to change Configure IP option from Automatic to Manual?
2. If yes, how to configure IP address and subnet mask?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to connect to a VPN network?

Comment: I am able to connect a specific WI-Fi network. But in order to run mobile data and Wi-Fi at the same time, IP address and subnet mask need to be added. I am not sure how to add them programmatically.

Comment: You want WIFI for LAN, 3G for WAN? You can see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

***1.*** In Xarmain.ios `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` is from Apple's native method.

**NEHotspotConfigurationManager** refer to [this from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager) , [this from xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager/)

*A configuration manager that applies and removes hotspot configurations of Wi-Fi networks.*

So it can not configure IPV4 address and Subnet Mask

---

***2.*** However, **NEIPv4Settings**

*NEIPv4Settings contains the Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) settings of a IP layer network tunnel.*  can do that.you can refer to [here from apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neipv4settings) , [here from xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/NetworkExtension.NEIPv4Settings/)

They are all extend from **NetworkExtension** (*Configure VPN tunnels. Customize and extend core networking features.*)

**So** you can use `NEIPv4Settings` to do that.

If you want connect to a wireless access point that is not connected to the internet.The Wifi connection is established fine and I can access other devices on that LAN.In ios,you can do that.

---

***3.*** **Workaround**

The Wifi connection on the iPhone/iPad must be configured as a static connection. You must specify an unused IP in the range of the wifi access point (e.g. 192.168.0.2). Specify a mask (255.255.255.0). ***Do NOT enter any router IP***.

Once connected to that wifi network, you can access other devices connected to the same wifi LAN (e.g. 192.168.0.*).

And do that, WAN is accessible through 3G!

---

**More info**: If want to do VPN, you can study `NEVPNManager` ,also extend from `NetworkExtension`.

Comment: #2 seems like the cleanest way to go. Can you direct to implementation example? Cant find anything on the web (new to native IOS)

Comment: @BlueBot Sorry for not having the sample code now ...

Comment: no worries its all good :) If Ill find something solid Ill come back and edit it in to your answer

Comment: @BlueBot That's great ! If find the sample code also will update here :-)